# PostgreSQL refusing to only display just month and year

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, format

This is the original table

```
"facultyid","courseid","datequalified"  
2143,"ISM 3112","9/1988"  
2143,"ISM 3113","9/1988"  
3467,"ISM 4212","9/1995"  
3467,"ISM 4930","9/1996"  
4756,"ISM 3112","9/1991"  
4756,"ISM 3113","9/1991"  

CREATE TABLE qualified (
    facultyid integer NOT NULL,
    courseid character varying(16) NOT NULL,
    datequalified character varying(16),
    dq2 date
);


ALTER TABLE qualified OWNER TO postgres;

--
-- TOC entry 2136 (class 0 OID 16441)
-- Dependencies: 190
-- Data for Name: qualified; Type: TABLE DATA; Schema: class_scheduling_01; Owner: postgres
--

INSERT INTO qualified (facultyid, courseid, datequalified, dq2) VALUES (3467, 'ISM 4212', '9/1995', '1995-09-01');
INSERT INTO qualified (facultyid, courseid, datequalified, dq2) VALUES (4756, 'ISM 3112', '9/1991', '1991-09-01');
INSERT INTO qualified (facultyid, courseid, datequalified, dq2) VALUES (2143, 'ISM 3113', '9/1988', '1988-09-01');
INSERT INTO qualified (facultyid, courseid, datequalified, dq2) VALUES (4756, 'ISM 3113', '9/1991', '1991-09-01');
INSERT INTO qualified (facultyid, courseid, datequalified, dq2) VALUES (2143, 'ISM 3112', '9/1988', '1988-09-01');
INSERT INTO qualified (facultyid, courseid, datequalified, dq2) VALUES (3467, 'ISM 4930', '9/1996', '1996-09-01');
```

I didn't know how to store the value, with just month and year, so I decided to use varchar type. From there I decided if I wanted to perform date query commands, I would have to convert it from a string to date. One query I'd like to perform is finding out which faculty ID is associated with dates after 1991.

I used the following to_date function to convert the string to date:
UPDATE qualified SET dq2 = to_date(datequalified, 'MM\YYYY')

the dq2 column was output as the following:

```
dq2
1995-09-01
1991-09-01
1988-09-01
1991-09-01
1988-09-01
1996-09-01
```

Is it possible to get dq2 output as just month and year, and still permit, date related queries?

Comment: There is no data type that holds only a part of a date. The only way is either to convert it to a string or filter upon retrieval and processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT to_char(your_date, 'YYYY-MM') AS month_format
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: Alright thanks! I guess from there I would make a virtual table/view that would ignore the dq2 column, and 'permanently' have the dq2 column As month_format.
SELECT to_char(dq2, 'MM/YYYY') AS month_format
FROM qualified

Comment: To perform a query on the said view's qualified date column:
SELECT *
FROM qualified_view1
WHERE to_date(datequalified, 'MM YYYY') >= '01/01/1993';

Comment: yes, the data will be still a regular `date` with `01` as day